# How to collapse repeated functions into a master function?

Tags: r, function, shiny

The MWE code below works as intended. However, how I got here seems sloppy with the shinyMatrix package function, `matrixInput`, repeated 3x and my attempt to consolidate these into custom functions `firstInput` and `secondInput`. Is there recommended best practice for consolidating repeated functions? Or is it better to eliminate my `firstInput` and `secondInput` and just use the longer `matrixInput` throughout for understandability/debugging reasons?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

firstInput <- function(inputId,y){ # << y = y col default value of input matrix
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = matrix(c(10,5), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c("1st input"),c("X and Y",""))),
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(
                           extend = FALSE, 
                           names = TRUE, 
                           editableNames = FALSE,
                           multiheader=TRUE
                          ),
              class = "numeric")}

secondInput <- function(inputId,y){ # << y = y col default value of input matrix
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = matrix(c(10,y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c("2nd input"),c(1,""))),
              label = "Add, delete, or modify matrix parameters:",
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(
                           extend = TRUE,
                           delta = 2,
                           delete = TRUE,
                           names = TRUE, 
                           editableNames = FALSE,
                           multiheader=TRUE
                          ),
              class = "numeric")}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("panel"),
      actionButton("showSecond","Show 2nd input (modal)",width = "100%")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
 
  output$panel <- renderUI({firstInput("input1")})
  
  observeEvent(input$showSecond,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        if(is.null(input$input2))
          {secondInput("input2",input$input1[1,2])} else
           {matrixInput("input2",
                         value = input$input2,
                         label = "Add, delete, or modify matrix parameters:",
                         rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
                         cols =  list(
                                      extend = TRUE,
                                      delta = 2,
                                      delete = TRUE,
                                      names = TRUE,
                                      editableNames = FALSE,
                                      multiheader=TRUE
                                     ),
                        class = "numeric")
            }, # closes else
        footer = modalButton("Close")
      ))
  })
  
  observe({ # << Assign sequential col header to matrix based on groupings of two
    req(input$input2)
    mm <- input$input2
    colnames(mm) <- trunc(1:ncol(mm)/2)+1 
    isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, "input2", mm))
  })
  
  output$secondInput <- renderUI({
    req(input$input1)
    secondInput("input2",input$input1[1,2])
  })
  
  outputOptions(output,"secondInput",suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) 
  
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({
    req(input$input1)
    plot(rep(if(isTruthy(input$input2)){input$input2[1,2]} else {input$input1[1,2]}, times=10))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the MWE code with a consolidation of the various matrixInput functions used in the original post. I hope this is understandable! At least it's shorter than the original post.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

###################################################################################################
#  a = matrix to input into matrixInput            d = delta # of columns when extending columns  #
#  b = variable for y column of input matrix       e = user option to delete column               #
#  c = extend matrix columns (T/F)                                                                #
################################################################################################### 

# matValues... feed into matrixInput as initial matrix; b parameter is for initial "Y" value
  matValue1 <- function(b){matrix(c(10,b), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c("1st input"),c("X and Y","")))}
  matValue2 <- function(b){matrix(c(10,b), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c("2nd input"),c(1,"")))}

myInput <- function(inputId,a,c,d,e){ 
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = a,
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(extend = c, 
                           delta = d,
                           delete = e,
                           names = TRUE, 
                           editableNames = FALSE,
                           multiheader=TRUE),
              class = "numeric")}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("panel"),
      actionButton("showSecond","Show 2nd input (modal)",width = "100%")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
 
  output$panel <- renderUI({myInput("input1",matValue1(256),FALSE,1,FALSE)})
  
  observeEvent(input$showSecond,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        if(is.null(input$input2))
          {myInput("input2",matValue2(input$input1[1,2]),TRUE,2,TRUE)}
            else {myInput("input2",input$input2,TRUE,2,TRUE)}, 
        footer = modalButton("Close")
      ))
  })
  
  observe({ # << Assign sequential col header to matrix based on groupings of two
    req(input$input2)
    mm <- input$input2
    colnames(mm) <- trunc(1:ncol(mm)/2)+1 
    isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, "input2", mm))
  })
  
  output$secondInput <- renderUI({
    req(input$input1)
    myInput("input2",matValue2(input$input1[1,2]),TRUE,2,TRUE)
  })
  
  outputOptions(output,"secondInput",suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) 
  
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({
    req(input$input1)
    plot(rep(if(isTruthy(input$input2)){input$input2[1,2]} else {input$input1[1,2]}, times=10))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```